# CSS positioning help

Tags: css

http://rent.neighborrow.com/items/herndon  need help moving the need have tabs to the right

```
    <div  id="tabs" style="width:350px;height:50px;">
        <ul style="width:320px;height:35px;">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">USERS Have</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">USERS Want</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" style="width:350px;height:50px;"">

            <ul class="user_have_list" style="width:350px;height:50px;">
                <?php if(count($approved_items)): ?>
                <?php foreach($approved_items as $item): ?>
                <?
                //print_r($item);
                ?>
                <li style="width:330px"><?= $html->link($item["items"]["item"], array("controller" => "items", "action" => "view", $item["items"]["id"])); ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li  style="width:330px"><a href="#">Nothing Here</a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" style="width:350px;height:50px;"">
            <ul class="user_want_list">
            <?php
            //if($_SESSION[Auth][User][id]!="")
            if(1==1)
                {
            if(count($requests)): ?>
                <?php foreach($requests as $request): ?>
                    <li  style="width:330px"><?= $html->link($request["Request"]["item"], array("controller" => "requests", "action" => "view", $request["Request"]["id"])); ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li  style="width:330px">Nothing</li>
            <?php endif; } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using firebug, I added float:right; inside the div='tabs'.is this what you want?

```
<div  id="tabs" style="width:350px;height:50px;float:right;">
```

Comment: probably- id have to see it... what line of code is that... im assuming in style.css?

Comment: also- i dont want the tabs to move on other pages so i dont necessarily want to play with the master css... what can i do to just move them right on THIS page for now

Comment: that's the 1st line of the code you posted here.since you use style attribute, just add the float:right; inside it.